# Xcode shows invalid warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, compiler-warnings

For some reason, I'm receiving many "Control reaches end of non-void function" warnings from Xcode despite the fact that I am returning a value. I get the warning in two functions (shown in the below image). In the first function, I call `return [super init]` and the return type is `id`, so I don't understand why I'm getting that warning. In the second function, the return type is void, and the warning specifies that the error is occurring in a **non-void** function. Basically, I'm wondering whether I'm making some mistake I'm not aware of, or if Xcode is just acting buggy.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's Xcode throwing a hissy fit for no reason. Possibly try clean and build to see if the errors still exist

Comment: @SuhailPatel - Thanks. That did the trick. Maybe you could post it as the answer?

Comment: No need to downvote.  Perfectly valid question and, yes, Xcode went off the rails (which can happen with odd syntax errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posted as answer as suggested by the author of the question with a bit more info]

Just running the project in most cases causes the compiler to just regenerate the linker files which have been affected since the last build and sometimes it's not perfect which is what causes these errors.

To solve, just Clean your project (Product -> Clean or Command-Shift-K) and then run your project. This causes any previously generated linker files to be destroyed (not a problem) and regenerated from scratch. The build will take longer than just simply running the project because it needs to build and link every class as opposed to just the ones that have changed when simply doing Run

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem. Try to clean and build again. Also `[super init]` should always be saved in self, like so:

```
self = [super init];
```

Comment: @SuhaliPatel actually answered this first in the comments, so that's why I marked him as the answer, but you also had the right idea, so I +1'd you. Also, in `init` methods, one usually calls `self = [super init];` and then at the end of the function says `return self`, but I'm not doing any custom initialization so I can simply say `return [super init];'

Comment: Downvoted my answer to change "dont" into "I don't", wow seriously? I try and help and this is the thanks I get.